# VIM and Carrot L (^L)?

Tags: key-bindings

I know when you see `^M` you can insert it with <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>; and `^I` with <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>. How do you generate a Form Feed `^L` for use in `:s` and `/`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To generate a Form Feed you can do <kbd>Control</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd>.

Comment: In searches (`:s` & `/`) you really need `^L`. For `^M` you can use `\r`, for `^I` (aka `<TAB>`) you can use `\t`. See `:help /\e` and following.

Comment: That's right. I don't normally use escape characters in VIM because I find the behavior in `[]` to be so intuitive with the `\s` and the like not working, guess I'm just scared. But it seems that \r and \t are not problematic.